# VS2010: Output Window not showing debug output until I fiddle with it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

A weird problem has just started happening on my system (and yes, I've tried rebooting).

When I run a C# program under the debugger, the "Show output from:" drop-down in the Output window automatically changes to "Debug" (just like it always has).

But now, the Output window is empty! It should have a bunch of Debug.WriteLine() stuff.

If I now select a different option from the "Show output from:" drop-down, and then re-select "Debug" the output appears correctly - it was hiding there all along.

This is quite annoying - has anyone else ever had this happen?

Just yesterday I installed the Visual Studio 11 beta, and I currently suspect that may be the cause. I haven't changed anything else on my system. Oh, I also installed NLog yesterday too.

Comment: Don't install beta software on a production machine you need to get your job done.  Unless you run it in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

This problem was nothing to do with the Visual Studio 2012 beta!

It was in fact the Visual Studio Editor Extensions for C# (v1.4.40602.0) for Code Contracts (from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85f0aa38-a8a8-4811-8b86-e7f0b8d8c71b/)

When I uninstalled that, the problem went away.